# Slick: Default arguments in prepared query (for limit and range)

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I want to do something like this in Slick 2.0.x: `select users with age <= maxAge or if maxAge is None, select all users (limited by a number)`. I tried this:

```
private def ageQuery(maxAge: Column[Option[Int]], limit: Column[Int]) = {
  Users.filter(user => maxAge.map(_ >= user.age).getOrElse(true)).take(limit)
}

val compiledAgeQuery = Compiled(ageQuery _)
```

I am running into following issues:

- `limit` is a `Column[_]`, but `Users.take` expects an `Int`. If I change it `limit` to `Int` then I can't use the `Compiled` macro anymore since that expects only `Column[_]`
- This snippet itself does not compile: `user => maxAge.map(_ >= user.age).getOrElse(true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found following solution to your problem:

```
private def ageQuery(maxAge: Column[Option[Int]] ,limit:  scala.slick.lifted.ConstColumn[Long]) = {
    Users.filter(_.age < maxAge.getOrElse(1000)).take(limit)
}
```

This is what I did:

1. I changed type of `limit` parameter to `scala.slick.lifted.ConstColumn[Long]`. Now it satisfies both `take` method and `Compiled` macro
2. I changed filtering condition. Now it returns all users younger then `maxAge`, and when `maxAge` is `None` then it returns all users younger than 1000 years. It is workaround but it works good (assuming that noone is older than 1000 years)